# Custom field handlers syntax when using the Jira/Rally Connector

Tags: jira, rally, connector, ca

I am working on a Jira/Rally (CA Agile Central) integration and can get a basic sync to work, however some fields require a more complex transformation when syncing them between Jira and Rally.

For this I can see that the CA Agile Connector (https://help.rallydev.com/jira-installation-user-guide) provides some support for "custom field handlers" which are written in Ruby and follow a format like:

```
# Copyright 2015 CA Technologies.  All Rights Reserved.
require 'rallyeif/wrk/field_handlers/field_handler'

module RallyEIF
  module WRK
    module FieldHandlers
      class MyCustomFieldHandler < OtherFieldHandler
        def initialize(field_name = nil)
          super(field_name)
        end

        # ... more code here ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However when I create that file and add the following to my connector config:

```
...
<Connector>
    <FieldMapping>
        <Field>
            <Rally>Description</Rally>
            <Other>Description</Other>
            <Direction>TO_RALLY</Direction>
        </Field>
        ...
    </FieldMapping>

    <OtherFieldHandlers>
        <MyCustomFieldHandler>
            <FieldName>Description</FieldName>
        </MyCustomFieldHandler>
    </OtherFieldHandlers>

</Connector>
...
```

When running the connector I get the following error:

```
[2017-08-22 20:25:39 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.rescue in block in read_field_handlers - For RallyEIF::WRK::JiraConnection: Could not find class for MyCustomFieldHandler
```

The documentation does not mention how to use the custom handlers at all, so I'm wondering if anyone has used this feature and can share some information on how to declare and use the custom field handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested connector version 4.7.2 and it worked.  Things to check:

- within the folder where the connector is invoked, there must be a folder named "field_handlers"
- within this "field_handlers" folder, there must be a file (as you have shown above) with "class MyCustomFieldHandler < ...."

There is an example on the help pages.  It's for HP-ALM (QC) not for JIRA, but the concept is the same:

- https://help.rallydev.com/QC-custom-fieldhandler.pxml

End of ideas so far.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was not using the "field_handlers" folder. I figured it out by unpacking the gem and looking at the source code. Once I moved my ruby code into that folder then it worked.